# How to close mmenu programmatically on click of submenu item?

Tags: mmenu

As the headline says, I can't reaaly close menu per code.

My submenu items are anchor links of the parent element like `site#anchor`

I want to close the menu after click on the anchorlink, if I'm on that page.

i tried it this way but its not working correctly

```js
menu.querySelectorAll('.level_2 a').forEach(bindClick);
            
function bindClick(item){
  if (item.href.substring(item.href.lastIndexOf('/')).indexOf(pathname) >= 0){
    let hash = item.getAttribute("href");
                    
    item.addEventListener("click", () => {
      scroll({
    top: document.querySelector(hash).offsetTop - document.getElementById('header_bottom').clientHeight,
        behavior: "smooth"
      });
      api.close();
    });
  }
}
```

The menu closes but the background of the menu doesnt disappear.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code.

```
menu.querySelectorAll('.level_2 a').forEach(bindClick);

function bindClick(item) {
  if (item.href.substring(item.href.lastIndexOf('/')).indexOf(pathname) >= 0) {
    let hash = item.getAttribute("href");
    enter code here
    item.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default link behavior

      scroll({
        top: document.querySelector(hash).offsetTop - document.getElementById('header_bottom').clientHeight,
        behavior: "smooth"
      });

      // Close the menu programmatically
      var menuElement = document.querySelector("#your-menu-selector"); // Replace with your menu selector
      // Close the menu using the appropriate method based on the menu library you're using
      // For example, if you're using the menulibrary, you can use:
      menuElement. menu.close();

      // If you're using a different menu library, refer to its documentation for the correct close method
    });
  }
}
```

Note: In this code, after performing the desired action (in this case, scrolling), the menu is closed programmatically. You'll need to replace "#your-menu-selector" with the correct selector for your menu element.

The specific method to close the menu programmatically will depend on the menu library you're using. The code snippet assumes you're using the menu library. If you're using a different library, make sure to refer to its documentation for the appropriate method to close the menu programmatically.

Comment: That sounds good. Im using this one https://mmenujs.com/. So it should be api.close() but that doesnt work.

Comment: Seems i got a typo in my code. it hasnt worked because i forgot to get the hash value -> the hash var got the href value in it